# How to remove SHA1 cert from chain in pem or crt file

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

We are sweeping our environment for Expired SHA-1 certificates in chain.

We get details of expired SHA1 cert from file with below command,

```
[root@webserver01~]# openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint -sha1 -enddate -inform pem. -in /etc/web01/ssl/web01_mycompany_com.pem
SHA1 Fingerprint=A2:C0:7F:DF:67:9B:EF:86:39:4E:E4:7B:D0:F8:74:36:74:CA:9F:27
notAfter=Oct  2 23:59:59 2019 GMT
```

How do I remove this specific expired SHA-1 cert in chain from `/etc/web01/ssl/web01_mycompany_com.pem` file using CLI.

So `/etc/web01/ssl/web01_mycompany_com.pem` file will be updated without SHA-1 cert.

Comment: Each cert is signed by the preceding certs in the chain, so there is no way to replace a cert and keep descendents.  You must generate new certs.

Comment: How to do that, I mean generating new certs also fine but how to generate new cert `(web01_mycompany_com.pem)`without having SHA1. I am new to ssl concept.

Comment: This is not a programming question.  There are many tutorials available depending on who controls the parent cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html`

`.pem` consists of chain of certificates, We just need to figure it out which one is expire and just remove that.

Open that `.pem` file in your favorite editor and copy each certificate one by one from
`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` and paste in above site.

[image]

It will show the details of certificate. If current cert which you paste in decoder is not expired then copy next cert in `.pem` file and check for end date.

Once you find the expired certs , Just remove it.
Make sure remove it Begin to End. Then save file and check again with openssl command.

**Note :- make sure take backup prior to change anything in `.pem` file.**